# Spring Soap Webservice exception handling

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, exception

I am creating soap web service using spring. I am getting hibernate exception while trying to save the request.
 I am trying to catch the hibernate exception in the catch block but control not even coming to the catch block
 and  soap service returning with the soap fault error message. Below are the list of classes which i am using, 
 Could any one please let me know how to handle the exception and rethrow the exception.

```
@WebService(serviceName = "submitService")
public class SubmitService extends AbstractWebServiceImpl {


    @Autowired
    private Validate validate;

    @WebMethod
    @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
    public ResponseData submitRequest(RequestData request) {
            ResponseData response = validate.submitRequest(request);
            return response;

    }

}
```

My Base class

```
 public class AbstractWebServiceImpl extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {    
        @Resource
        private WebServiceContext webServiceContext;

        protected void handleWSException(Exception e) throws BusinessFault, InfrastructureFault {
            if ( e instanceof BusinessException) {
                ReturnMessage rm = ((BusinessException)e).getReturnMessage();
                throw new BusinessFault(rm, e);

            } else if (e instanceof BaseException) {
                ReturnMessage rm = ((BaseException)e).getReturnMessage();
                throw new InfrastructureFault(rm, e);

            } else {
                ReturnMessage rm = new ReturnMessage(ReturnCode.GENERIC_WEB_SERVICE_ERROR, e.toString());
                throw new InfrastructureFault(rm, e);
            }
        }

        public void setWebServiceContext(WebServiceContext webServiceContext) {
            this.webServiceContext = webServiceContext;
        }

        public WebServiceContext getWebServiceContext() {
            return webServiceContext;
        }

    }
```

My Business layer implementation class

```
  @Component
    public class ValidateImpl implements Validate {


        @Autowired
        private SomeHibernateDao dao;

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public ResponseData submitRequest(RequestData request) {
            ResponseData response = new ResponseData();

             try {
                    dao.save(request);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                // Control never execute this block of code if dao layer throwing any exception.
                //  I want to catch the exception here modify the response and return to the client
                  e.printStackTrace(); 
                  response.setErrorDetails("More meaningful error message");
                }

            return response;
        }
```

This code returning default soap error message back to client. 
I want to catch the exception and modify the exception before returning to client. Please let me know what change i have to make so that i can handle the soap error message before i return the response back to client.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to catch the exception in SubmitService itself but not sure why not able to catch the exception in ValidateImpl. however my issue is resolved now.